# Kotlin coroutines parallelization

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am having some trouble launching coroutines in parallel.

I have some code that makes a network request in a coroutine, this network request returns a collection of intermediate results, which I would like to fetch the complete result for each item in this collection in parallel (i.e. not sequentially).

Here is the relevant API's:

```
data class IntermediateResult(val id: Long)

data class FinalResult(val id: Long, val name: String)

suspend fun getIntermediateResults() : Collection<IntermediateResult>

suspend fun getFinalResult(id: Long) : FinalResult
```

And here is the code that is consuming the API's (it's inside a ViewModel):

```
fun example() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { 
        val intermediateResults = getIntermediateResults()
        
        intermediateResults.forEach { intermediateResult ->
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { 
                val finalResult = getFinalResult(intermediateResult.id)
                
                // Update cache and post updated cache to the UI via live data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It was my understanding that launching a new coroutine inside the `forEach` loop would cause the final result to be fetched for each item in a parallel fashion (i.e. it won't "wait" on the `getFinalResult` before continuing to the next iteration of the forEach) but, what I am observing is that it's happening sequentially (i.e. the call to `getFinalResult` in the forEach loop is causing the code to "wait" until the result comes back before starting the next iteration).

In other words, I don't care about the final results coming back in the order of iteration over the intermediate results.

If it's relevant (I'm fairly sure it's not) the implementation of the 2 suspend functions is using `suspendCoroutine` to wrap up old callback style code into suspend functions.

Comment: Does the GUI also freeze? You're using the `Main` dispatcher, so if `getFinalResult` is not a suspending function, that's what should happen. If `getFinalResult` already is a properly implemented suspendable function that uses an underlying async networking API, then the requests should execute in parallel, and at the very least the GUI should not freeze. But, if the GUI stays alive, and yet you don't get parallel requests, then that's probably up to the implementation/configuration of the networking library.

Comment: `getFinalResult` is a suspending function (it wraps up old callback style code using `suspendCoroutine`). The GUI is freezing yes, but I am observing the same behaviour if I use `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default)`.

Comment: I suggest focusing on the freezing GUI then, it should not happen if suspension is correctly implemented and used.